# What does "wash up" mean in this context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idioms

> Each year as much as 150,000 tons of plastic debris, most notably styrofoam, **washes up** on the shores of Japan.

What does *washes up* mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky phrasal verb, because it has at least three meanings:

- to clean one's face and hands : *go wash up before dinner*
- to be have the ocean currents and waves carry something to a beach : *after the shipwreck, most of the cargo washed up on the shores of the island*
- to be past one's prime : _he was a first-rate programmer back in the early 80s, but he hasn't kept up – he's washed up

You can find those meanings (or ones fairly close to that) listed [here](http://www.freedictionary.org/?Query=wash%20up).

Based on your context, it's the second meaning. The styrofoam is left strewn about on the beach.

Comment: I have to point out that 1. is another of those odd transpondian phrases. In the UK you cannot possibly wash up before dinner… the plates aren't dirty yet ;) In BrE wash up is to clean the dishes, wash is to clean your face.

Answer (score 1):

See Definition 19 on [dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wash+up).  It means that the ocean carries the debris to the shore, where it gets stuck.